# PATH=$PATH:`pwd` - What happens when this command is executed?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, paths

What happens when this command is executed?

```
PATH =$PATH:`pwd`
```

Error: Nothing happens when i execute the command in the terminal.

Comment: See also, [How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/q/60218/295286)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you execute the command in your question, you should get an error message:

```
$ PATH =$PATH:`pwd`
bash: PATH: command not found
```

If the space is a typo, and you actually run this:

```
PATH=$PATH:`pwd`
```

Then that will add the current directory (`pwd` is a command that prints the path of the current directory, and `` `pwd` `` will be replaced with the output of `pwd`) to the `PATH` variable for the duration of your current shell session (util you close the terminal). To illustrate:

```
$ pwd
/home/terdon/foo  ## I am in /home/terdon/foo

$ echo $PATH ## the current PATH
/home/terdon/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

$ PATH=$PATH:`pwd`
$ echo $PATH
/home/terdon/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/terdon/foo
```

Note how the current directory, `/home/terdon/foo` has been added to the end of the `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 2):

#### The error

As far as your original command goes,  [terdon's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1038137/295286) already covers very well what is happening and what should happen. Let's analyze that slightly in more detail.

What you're trying to do is variable assignment, which should take form of:

```
varName=value
```

However, because of the space this is treated as a command `PATH` with command line argument consisting of a `=` then contents of variable `$PATH` and command-substitution of `pwd`, all joined in to same string:

```
PATH =$PATH:`pwd`
```

Of course, there is no such command as `PATH`, hence you will get an error.

Shell treats simple commands and their arguments as list of one or more space-separated tokens (with perhaps optional variable assignment before that). In other words, the form should be:

```
[VAR=value] word [arg1 [arg2 [arg3] ]...]
```

Of course, this is not what is desired in this case.

#### The proper command

So what *should have been done* is this:

```
PATH=$PATH:`pwd`
```

Here we have proper variable assignment, where in accordance with [the expansion order](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions), `bash` shell would first perform variable expansion, i.e. replace `$PATH` with whatever you have in that variable currently, then perform command-substitution where it runs `pwd` and replaces it with output of `pwd`. In the end, all that gets assigned back to `PATH` variable.

A few key observations:

- Since this is variable assignment, you don't need to quote `$PATH` variable, but usually you should to avoid undesirable behavior. See [When is Double Quoting Necessary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68748/85039)
- backticks form of command substitutions is [not recommended nowadays](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126928/85039). In this particular case, it's OK, but in general backticks don't lend themselves nicely to nesting and multi-line commands.
- `PATH` variable is used by shell to find commands, and the order of directories on that list sets the precedence to where commands would be searched. So for example, when you execute a command the shell would first check whether the command is [built-in](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Builtin-Index.html#Builtin-Index), if it's not then it would look through all directories on the `PATH` variable. The `PATH=$PATH:$(pwd)` would make shell traverse everything else, and only then get to the directory that was given by `pwd`. By contrast, `PATH=$(pwd):$PATH` would start the search from  the directory returned by `pwd` first. So order of the assignment matters.